# Append a <br/> tag to a value inside a textarea jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would you append a 
 tag on a value inside a textarea, it only appends it after a keypress of SHIFT+ENTER,

here is my code to append on the text area and it does not work??

`$('#textarea').append("<br/>");` i think there are still something lacking.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ctyQZ/32/)

Thank you. . .

Comment: `\n` is newline; `<br>` is not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you actually wanting to place the characters in the value?

```
​$("textarea").val(function(i,v){
    return v + "<br/>";
});​​​​
```

Or simply add a new line?

```
​$("textarea").val(function(i,v){
    return v + "\nfoo";
});​​​​​​​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/SNeyy/

If you want to respond only to <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>:

```
$("textarea").on("keypress", function(e){
    if ( e.which === 13 && e.shiftKey ) {
        $(this).val(function(i,v){
            return v + "<br/>"; // or return v + "\n"; (whatever you want)
        });
    }
});​​​​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/SNeyy/1/

Comment: It sounded like tom wanted a new line char, like when you cntl+enter it. +1up for both solutions.

Comment: @ToddBFisher , thanks for the enlightment hehe , yah that was wat i wanted a new line

Comment: @tomexsans I've updated to address the `shift+enter` request.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to change the value of the `textarea`. To add the string "<br/>" you have to use

```
$('#textarea').val($('#textarea').val() + '<br/>');
```

and to add a new line you have to use

```
$('#textarea').val($('#textarea').val() + "\n");
```

Textarea can have only a text node as its child. `<textarea><br/></textarea>` is incorrect usage. If you want to add the string "<br/>", the html code should be

```
<textarea>&lt;br/&gt;</textarea>
```

and to add a new line, the html code should be

```
<textarea>
</textarea>
```

In other words, you **cannot** use `<textarea><br/></textarea>`

Comment: is there any way the <br/> tag is hidden in the textarea when i press shift enter it is displayed on the textarea

Comment: textarea can have only a text node as its content. If you want to append the string '<br/>' (not an actual line break), you can use `$('#textarea').append('&lt;br/&gt;')`. If you want to append a newline, you should use `$('#textarea').append("\n")`.